# QString remove "[1]" from string using QRegExp

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QString and I'd like to remove [1], [123], [4556]

```
    QString myStr= "aaa bbb ccc .[1]";
    myStr = myStr.remove(QRegExp("\[\[0-9]\]");
```

But its not working, any idea???

Answer (score 0):

Your QRegExp does not work. First QT requires you to double escape some characters depending on what you'd like to achive. Second you must not escape your range brackets. You need double escap for the bracket you like to match and no escape for the range bracket:

```
QRegExp("\\[[0-9]\\]");
```

Comment: It's not Qt that requires the double-escape, it's C++. If you want a backslash in an ordinary string literal, you need to escape it.

Comment: @Mat: true. QT sometimes requires this even if c++ wouldn`t. Not in this case though.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

`a.remove(QRegExp("\\[[0-9]+\\]"));`

First, you need double escape sequences around the outer square brackets in order to specify that those will actually show up in your string and then you need to specify the range that you want to match `[0-9]` and the fact that this range may show up once or more `+`.